# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle’s “when no data found” exception

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exception

I need SQL Server equivalent of Oracle’s  “when no data found” exception 
example:

```
EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         RETURN 0;
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         RETURN 0;
```

converter to sql server

Comment: You could use @@ROWCOUNT to identify NO DATA, but dont know of an exception. Try this lInk http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=140165

Comment: thanks for your help, the link is something like

Comment: This is poor-quality code. Swallowing all exceptions and returning `0` no matter what failed is a recipe for a difficult-to-find bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @rc INT = 1
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...) SET @rc = 0
RETURN @rc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use exception handling then you can do the following:

```
BEGIN TRY
  /* your other code */

  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE [...])
    THROW 50000, 'Your error messages here!', 1
  
  /* more code */
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  /* exception handling goes here */
END CATCH
```

If not, the you can just use `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM blah)`

Answer (score 0):

use **@rowcount** to see how many records came out from a select statment.

select @l_emp_name = emp_name
from employees
where employee_id = 1313;

if @@rowcount > 1  ---in oracle this means TOO_MANY_ROWS
Print  'too many rows!!'

if @@rowcount = 0  ---in oracle this means NO_DATA_FOUND
Print  'too many rows!!'

if @@rowcount = 1  ---in oracle this means one record there
Print  'got 1 records'

Comment: How about WHEN OTHERS?

Comment: well i cannont see others here if the table exist and the column list correct ..etc.

you only can get 0, 1 or many records.

Comment: SQL server does not through TOO_MANY_ROWS kind of exception. When you select into a simple variable where the query returns many records, the value from the last record is stored on to the variable. Basically values from previous records get overwritten by the last record.